# Уверенно/уверено

Tags: удвоенные-буквы

Добрый день! Ув. филологи, помогите разобраться!

... медленно, но уверенно делать свою работу.

Answer (score 2):

В данных словах пишется две Н, т.к. это наречия, образованные от прилагательных, у которых было две Н.